# JSF 2.0 & Cassandra - How to get started

Tags: jsf, cassandra, hector

Here come a few newbie questions on using Cassandra with JSF 2.0. I'm in the start of a web application and want to use Cassandra as a backend. My app should be deployed in different regions and hence the same data should be available/replicated in/to all regions.

I would like to have general information about best practices.

I have the following setup:

- Maven2
- JSF 2.0 (currently using Managed Beans and JPA)
- Glassfish 3.2.1

Which driver would you recommend?

- cassandra-jdbc driver implemented with datastax community edition?
- Or Hector, which seems to be the most advanced client?

If Hector how would I use Hector properly within a JSF project?

- Hector JPA integration (could not find any information on how to use)?
- Using Hector directly from Managed Beans without JPA?

How would I use the driver best in a JSF 2.0 web application?

- Managed Beans?
- Singleton Bean?
- POJOs?

*(I'm not very familiar with Java EE yet, but in the process of building up knowledge)*

How would I structure the classes/beans so that connections can be pooled?

Is there maybe an open source example that is using JSF/Java EE or JSF/POJO to see how such as setup is used in best practice?

What are your opinions on how to start such a project from scratch?

I'm thankful for all hints you can give me. I'm struggling since a month to find enough information to get started on this project.

Answer (score 0):

> Which driver would you recommend?
>
> ```
> * cassandra-jdbc driver implemented with datastax community edition?
> * Or Hector, which seems to be the most advanced client?
> ```

I would probably suggest hector as this project status is active. There are many q&a, articles and manuals that can be found online and that help greatly when you starting to learn this new technology. But that does not means cassandra-jdbc driver is lack of materials that can be found online. This is my personal preference development using hector library from version 0.8 to the current latest version.

> If Hector how would I use Hector properly within a JSF project?
>
> ```
> * Hector JPA integration (could not find any information on how to use)?
> * Using Hector directly from Managed Beans without JPA?
> ```
>
> How would I use the driver best in a JSF 2.0 web application?
>
> ```
> * Managed Beans?
> * Singleton Bean?
> * POJOs?
> ```
>
> (I'm not very familiar with Java EE yet, but in the process of
>   building up knowledge)
>
> How would I structure the classes/beans so that connections can be
>   pooled?
>
> Is there maybe an open source example that is using JSF/Java EE or
>   JSF/POJO to see how such as setup is used in best practice?

You should really read and study into these repository.

- [cassandra-queue-spring](https://github.com/btoddb/cassandra-queue-spring)
- [hector object mapper](https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/object-mapper)

I don't have experience in JPA so I can't comment further but it seem that hector has the JPA classes that you will be interested in. Be sure to check out this [Hector Object Mapper](https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Hector-Object-Mapper-%28HOM%29) introduction.

> What are your opinions on how to start such a project from scratch?

It's probably difficult to start everything from scratch if you are new JavaEE but this [link](https://github.com/btoddb/cassandra-queue-spring) should provide you assistance when you start your own project.